# Accessing new model objects after Code First migration

Tags: entity-framework

Ok, I have followed this article very closely:

[Entity Framework Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

It is well written, clear, concise, and best of all it pretty much matches my exact situation (but with different table names).  There is a piece of information which is missing.  After the migration to add a 'Posts' table is put in place, how do you access the data in the 'Posts' table?

I think that there should probably be a PostsContext.  Or should there be a single context with all the objects?  Should the existing BlogContext be updated to allow access to Posts?  If that is done, there ends up being errors when doing the migration stating "There is already an object named 'Posts' in the database".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the best way to do this is to have multiple DbContext objects.  When I created a new class and inherited from the DbContext and essentially had a PostContext object, it happily got me the information from the database.  My PostContext was very similar to the BlogContext.

My Disclaimer:  I have read plenty of threads that indicated having separate DbContexts made sense so that you can keep your database access modular.  I couldn't agree more.  However, I have also read that it is good to have a global DbContext to represent everything.  While this doesn't seem like a good idea to me, I really wanted to get this to work since I literally have only 2 tables.  In the end, I couldn't update my context class.  I really wanted to figure out how to get that to work.  The way I have it just has a certain smell to it that I just don't feel this is the *best* approach.  But, with only needing 2 tables, I'm ok with it.